# How to find the session id of running jobs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to get the session id of executing jobs

```
;with JobDetails as
(
select Job_Id = left(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       Step = substring(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)+1,charindex(')',intr1)-charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       SessionId = spid
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses x 
    cross apply (select replace(x.program_name,'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job ','')) cs (intr1)
    where spid > 50 and x.program_name like 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %'
)
select * 
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    inner join JobDetails jd on j.job_id = jd.Job_Id
```

but it throws the following error

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 47 Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I tried to cast the `job_id` to `varbinary` but it produces no result

```
;with JobDetails as
(
select Job_Id = left(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       Step = substring(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)+1,charindex(')',intr1)-charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       SessionId = spid
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses x 
    cross apply (select replace(x.program_name,'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job ','')) cs (intr1)
    where spid > 50 and x.program_name like 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %'
)
select * 
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    inner join JobDetails jd on cast(j.job_id as varbinary) = jd.Job_Id
```

but when I copy paste a `job_id` from `cte` like this

```
select job_id, name 
    from msdb..sysjobs 
    where job_id = 0x128A47A31EAB8F4DA1AD852093D815F5
```

it **works**. Any idea how to fix this query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `CONVERT` to convert the msdb.dbo.sysjob.job_id to `BINARY(16)` and then used `CONVERT` (and a *style*) to convert that to a varchar(max) which could be compared to what comes out of your cte.  You can read more about `CONVERT` and styles by reviewing the documentation for [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). This worked in my testing.

Try this:

```
;
WITH JobDetails
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Job_Id = left(intr1, charindex(':', intr1) - 1)
        ,Step = substring(intr1, charindex(':', intr1) + 1, charindex(')', intr1) - charindex(':', intr1) - 1)
        ,SessionId = spid
    FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses x
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT replace(x.program_name, 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job ', '')
        ) cs(intr1)
    WHERE spid > 50
        AND x.program_name LIKE 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %'
    )
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN JobDetails jd ON jd.Job_Id = convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(BINARY (16), j.job_id), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks mate thats it... WTHeck is that `1` doing. I always thought styles are only used for date formatting